# Cross compile for ARM using gcc-multilibs

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation

There are various questions available in AskUbuntu related to Cross compiling. They were not of much help to me.

I used to work on gcc-4.5/4.6 for ARM. It was available in Ubuntu repo under the name `gcc-4.*-arm-linux-gnueabi`

My host linux is running on Ubuntu-12.04. When I planned to move to the latest GCC cross compilers of version 4.7/4.8, it was found that these were the only list of packages available in repo:

```
gcc-4.*             
gcc-4.*-base        
gcc-4.*-doc         
gcc-4.*-locales     
gcc-4.*-multilib    
gcc-4.*-plugin-dev  
gcc-4.*-source
```

I could not find a version specifically for ARM compilers. `gcc-4.*-multilib` must be the package that handles all the cross compiling stuff. How could I use this package to cross compile for ARM on `soft-float`

I could not fetch much information from search engines. Even links that would help with my problem are appreciated.